# GTM / GA / Enhanced Ecommerce setup Best practices help is needed

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

I am new in dealing with GTM /GA / Enhanced Ecommerce tracking and seeking some advice on best practices. We will soon be implementing multiple sites (each having different locale) below is the example of the sites domain structure : www.mysite.com/uk- UK
    www.mysite.com/de- german
    www.mysite.com/in - india

Here is the approach that i think will work out best...i am planning to set one GTM Account since parent company is same (mysite) but different GTM containers (one for each country) We will be using same GA account for all the countries and all the variable/triggers/events for GA will be setup in their respective container.I will be implementing Enhanced Ecommerce via dataLayer  (GTM) and for each purchase, i will be prefixing order id with 2 digit country code i.e uk12345, de35535 etc.
How can i make sure that the GA events can be tracked separately for each country as well so that while looking at the reports, user should be able to track user for individual sites and even roll up the reports for the entire company.
Any best practices. screenshots explanations will b appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having just *one* GTM container, pointing to *one* GA property.
This is much simpler to maintain and manage.

You can then creates views for each of your countries, using filters on subdirectories (Filter Type: Predefined, Include only, traffic to subdirectories, that are equal to, "/in/" for instance). You can create a view with no filters, on top of it, for global reporting.
This also allows you to give users different access rights for each country, if you want an analyst to have access to only one country for instance.

You don't need to prefix the country code to each order number, the "Page" dimension in GA will give you the page from which the order have been passed, that should be including "/in/" or "/uk/".

In our case, we have multiple domains for our different countries (oursite.com.ng, oursite.ci, oursite.ma, etc.), one GA property per country, and one unique GTM containers pointing to the different GA properties thanks to a lookup variable in GTM. 
But I ended up copying the GA property settings 14 times (for our 14 countries), it would have been much better to do it only once.
Plus, to report cross-country, we had to use the API to avoid downloading and combining 14 reports every time.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian for replying. But creating a single GTM container can cause issues when we need to use any specific events for a specific country. Also, any other third party tags needed for a specific country can then be implemented within that container itself.Am i correct?

Comment: You are welcome.
To do country-specific stuff, you can use specific triggers, for you "Page Path contains "/in/" for instance.